# Save or Print Firebug output

Tags: firebug

I am using firebug to profile our webapp.

I am trying to make changes to speed it up.  I want to make sure that each change that I make increases the efficiency of the app.

What I would like to do is save or print the Net tab and the Javascript profile of the site I am viewing.  How can I do this?

*(I would just take a screenshot but the output spans several pages so taking a screenshot is not practical)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jan Odvarko at [Software is Hard](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/) has created two firebug plugins that allow you to export the console and the Net tab.

- The [ConsoleExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/) exports the console tab (including profiling) to html.
- The [NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/) exports the net tab to either the clipboard as an image or to a `.har` file.  A link is provided for Jan's har viewer however I found that this was quite slow and not very useful.  However exporting to an image file works great.

Comment: ConsoleExport doesn't work for Firefox 36.0.4 (current as of today)

Comment: following info in this thread (https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5182), you can set it up to download the console locally using this patch:  https://getfirebug.com/releases/consoleexport/consoleExport-0.5b5.xpi and then adding a firefox configuration extensions.firebug.consoleexport.defaultLogDir

Answer (score 8):

Here you go: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/

Comment: The link is broken... :/