# background-image won't display

Tags: css, background-image

I have a CSS `background-image` issue that I can't figure out.

Here it is:

**CSS**

```
#yes {
   background-image:url("../tick.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
}​

#no {
   background-image:url("../cross.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
    <td id="yes"></td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td id="no"></td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
```

**Result**

[image: #no doesn't work!?]

No matter what I do, I can't get the `#no` id to work.

- I can browse to the img via a web browser and it works.
- I've replaced `cross.png` with `tick.png` (which I know works) and it still doesn't work.
- I've tried using the fully qualified path `background-image:url("http://.../cross.png");` but still no joy.

I don't know what else troubleshoot?

I know I can just use `<img...` (which works fine) but I don't want to be defeated.

Can someone just put me out of my misery!?

Massive thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the website? if not... please make sure both the images are 16x16. background-position: center center;

Comment: what does the console say (F12)?

Comment: Is your `#no` element unique ?

Comment: The website is a self-hosted internal site so can't post the link.

Comment: Yes, `#no` is unique.

Comment: Try changing it from "no" to "somethingelse" in both files, same behavior?

Comment: Add this to `#no` and see what happens: `background-size: 16px;`. Are you getting a 404 in your console or anything like that? Perhaps the file is misplaced or misspelled.

Comment: Do you have any other css formatting that is applied to `#no`? Have you checked the dom including the actual style settings in the development tools of the browser of your choice ( e.g. right click over the table cell and choose 'inspect element' in chrome)  ?

Comment: `#no` to `anotherid` - same behaviour.

Comment: Using Firebug for Chrome and inspecting the element, the `#yes` returns `background-image url(http://n03-webcast-...` in the Computed tab which is correct. `#no` returns nothing (blank)!?

Comment: So are you saying it doesn't have any style defined for the #no id?  Are #yes and #no defined in the same CSS file?

Comment: `background-size: 16px;` didn't work.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but your code look like this? http://www.bootply.com/sSgIttQJsJ which is the complete url image?

Comment: @JBaczuk Yes, `#yes` and `#no` are in the same .css file. Using Inspect, it appears to have no style?

Comment: It needs some style :).  Can you post everything about the DOM object that firebug lists in the style pane?

Comment: @JBaczuk It won't let me post everything from the DOM as it's too long!

Comment: Try to put the `tick.png` image in `#yes` and `#no` class, if it works, the issue is because your `cross.png` is corrupted.

Comment: @PatrickFerreira Tried that, same issue!?

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b there must be a conflict if it doesn't assign the style to the DOM object.  Try using a class instead of an id just for kicks.

Comment: @JBaczuk Using classes - same! :(

Comment: Would it help if I hosted the 2 .css and .htm files?

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b It might help, but it sounds like you have a problem that will be difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the console output when you load the page.  Make sure you look at the console and see if there are any errors.  Also, make sure you clear the browser cache.

Comment: @JBaczuk Is there a way to export the results from the DOM screen?

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b I think you have to install an add-on.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996878/save-or-print-firebug-output.  Try adding the CSS directly in the console and make sure that works.

Comment: CSS: http://adventureworldplay.co.uk/files/style.css
HTML: http://adventureworldplay.co.uk/files/Template.html

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b there is some strange character after the definition for #yes, what is that?  #yes {
   background-image:url("../tick.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
}â€‹

Comment: @JBaczuk No idea, they're not there in Notepad++?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70160/discussion-between-kungfauxn00b-and-jbaczuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so with the assistance of [JBaczuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3499115/jbaczuk), he identified some strange characters included in the CSS file.

[image]

This was stopping the rest of the CSS file from being parsed.

Notepad++ didn't display these character and neither did Notepad. A quick Google found this [Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001682/special-char-added-to-css-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-where-did-this-come-from) which gives an explanation (which was over my head).

To resolve my issue, I simply deleted the `#yes` and `#no` ids and recreated them (this time using classes and it seems to have resolved my issue.

Hope this helps someone else in the future as I was literally pulling my hair out.

Thanks to all those who helped!

Comment: glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't change too much your code and it works... something with the `#no` selector, maybe it's not unique, or something wrong with [the priority of your selectors](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector)

```css
#yes,
#no {
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
#yes {
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Yes_Check_Circle.svg");
}
#no {
  background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/No_Cross.svg");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="yes"></td>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td id="no"></td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```